# Como inserir um caractere em determinada posição de uma string?

Tags: javascript, string

Como inserir um caractere em determinada posição de uma string?

Ex: tenho a string `"abcdefg"` e quero adicionar `,` antes do `"f"` pra ficar `"abcde,fg"`, como fazer isso?

Comment: O que você tentou até agora? Nos mostre algum código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```js
var a = "abcdefg";
var b = ",";
var position = 5;
var output = [a.slice(0, position), b, a.slice(position)].join('');
console.log(output);
```